# Android rounded corners layout bug

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, rounded-corners

I try to create not full screen Activity with transparency around it and use this layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerPageContainer">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/informationContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_corners"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

And for rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

But have received this result with defects on corners, bottom and top sides:

[image]

Help me to fix it please.

Comment: Looks like shape inside a window with AlertDialog style.

Comment: Yes, and what, how can I receive white color filled `Activity` with rounded corners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found solution:

1) Create theme XML in `res/values/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

2) Rounded corners style `drawable/rounded_corners.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

3) Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/qrCodeContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounder_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

4) Describe `Activity` in project manifest XML:

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.ViewCodeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

</activity>
```

Comment: Exelent! It is exactly that i have tryed to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Covering AlertDialog themed view with shape is not a good idea as you see.
There you have tutorial:
http://darshangr.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/creating-a-transparent-view-in-android-login-screen-example/

Naturally you'll need to modify it. Instead of white backgroud set your shape with rounded corners.

Comment: Should work. Haven't tested but it is the most complete example I've found.

Comment: The main idea is to create transparent activity and show view in it which has background with rounded corners.